# Check on app resume for server file changes?

Tags: ios

I have a Data plist (conveniently named `Data.plist`) that is updated on launch of the app:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Determile cache file path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [paths objectAtIndex:0],@"Data.plist"];

    NSString *dataURLString = @"http://link/to/Data.plist";
    NSURL *dataURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:dataURLString];
    NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dataURL];
    [plistData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"The bundle is %@", filePath);
    self.data = dict;

    // Configure and show the window
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I'd like to be able to have some way of checking the saved plist against the server plist - I've seen some implementations that use external libraries but there has to be something in the original iOS SDK. Any ideas? I've read whatever code I do end up using needs to be implemented in `viewWillAppear` but I'm not sure **what** that code is exactly.

Comment: If you're going to check against the server's plist, you'll either need to send yours to the server (so the server can do the compare), or get the server's (so you can compare them).  So why not just re-fetch the plist from the server every time and be done with it?

Comment: If I have to re-fetch each time, I'll have to move all the calls from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, won't I? How do I go about that?

Comment: Yes, put them in `applicationDidBecomeActive` which is called whether the app starts fresh or is re-started from running in the background.  But @Jack Lawrence's answer is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Two things... first, `dataWithContentsOfURL:` and generally any of Apple's (temptingly convenient) `<anything>WithContentsOfURL:` methods are **extremely unsafe** in the real world. It's **blocking** which means that no other code will execute until your request succeeds or fails. That means that if the server isn't available or your device doesn't have internet or for some other reason cannot retrieve your data, your phone will sit there until either the iOS watchdog process kills your app for freezing for too long, or it just fails. Then the rest of your app that is expecting data will freak out because suddenly you have no data when your code assumes you should. This is one of many problems with synchronous requests.

I won't go into how to implement asynchronous requests, but head over to Apple's documentation or you can use a wrapper framework like http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ that does it for you. Also have a look at http://www.cocoabyss.com/foundation/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/

To answer your actual question, you could have a tiny text file on your server with a version number or time stamp and download that along with your plist. on subsequent launches, you can pull down the time stamp/version number and compare it against the one you've got stored, and if the version on the server is more recent, then you pull it and save the new time stamp/version number.