# Extracting data from an audio file

Tags: ios

We have a web services function to which we are uploading an audio file into to be saved in the server. The code that I am using to create a data buffer (to pass to the web services) of the contents of the audio file is :

```
  NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fnWithSlash];
  audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL];
  NSLog(@"audiodata%d",audioData.length);
```

Here fnWithSlash contains the full path of the file. However audioData.length is always 0.
What am i missing?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is a _synchronous_ method. It will block your user interface until the network returns the audio file. That *will* result in an unresponsive user interface until the network request is finished, and *could* result in a crash if the iOS watchdog quits your application because of that unresponsiveness. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9122690/495384

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSData's dataWithContentsOfFile: instead..If the file is in your bundle it will look like the example below, otherwise construct the filePath of the sound file to your desired location..

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourSound" ofType:@"wav"];  
audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"audiodata%d",audioData.length);
```

Comment: An update: The original code did indeed work. Sorry about the false alarm!